# Canvas resizes on width but not height

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

When I create a canvas such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<canvas style="background-color: #FF0000; width: 100%; height: 100%></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

I've found that if I make the window small enough, the width will be scaled but not the height. That is, the canvas resizes proportionally but only enough so that the width fits in completely --- the height may need scrolling.

I would like instead to have the entire canvas resized proportionally so that it fits all on the page (both horizontally and vertically). Moreover, I would like to do this in a way such that the width and height attributes of the canvas aren't altered (though it's okay if the clientWidth/clientHeight is).

Answer (score 1):

### Fullscreen canvas

**Canvas display size**

The canvas is a special case in regard to sizing. It has a resolution the defines the number of pixels that it contains, and it has a display size that defines how many pixels it occupies on the page.

Canvas display size is set via its style properties.

```
canvas.style.width = "100%";  // does not change the resolution
canvas.style.height = "100%";
```

**Canvas resolution**

To set the resolution you set the canvas width and height properties.

```
canvas.width = 1000; // if the style width and height not set then
canvas height = 800;  // the computed style will match. If not
                      // then setting the resolution will
                      // not effect display size (in most cases.)
```

> **Note** that canvas sizing style properties required unit type '%', 'px', ... while canvas size properties do not and will assume the values are pixels ('px") if you just set them as a number.

**Low quality due to bad sizing.**

If you only set the style `width` and `height` you end up stretching out the default canvas resolution of 300 by 150 pixels and the resulting image is blurred due to bilinear filtering.

**Example** of default canvas resolution and style only sizing.

```js
var ctx = myCan.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "18px arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Low res & blury",myCan.width/2,myCan.height/2);
ctx.font = "12px arial";
ctx.fillText("Canvas resolution default " + myCan.width + "px by " + myCan.height + "px",myCan.width/2,myCan.height/2 + 18);
```

```css
    html, body {
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    canvas {
        width : 100%;
        height : 100%;
        background:#aaa;
    }
```

```html
    <canvas id="myCan"></canvas>
```

**Fullscreen (page) canvas**

To correctly size the canvas in both display size and resolution (both of which should match for the best result (not stretching) it is best done via javascript.

If I am doing a full screen canvas I prefer to position it via absolute positioning.

```
canvas.style.position = "absolute"
canvas.style.top = "0px";
canvas.style.left = "0px";
```

And I do not set the canvas display size by setting style width ad height, I allow that browser to compute that for me once I set the canvas resolution

**Example** correctly setting a full screen canvas using javascript.

```js
myCan.style.position = "absolute"
myCan.style.top = "0px";
myCan.style.left = "0px";
// when page has loaded size the canvas resolution to fit the display
myCan.width = window.innerWidth; 
myCan.height = window.innerHeight; 
var ctx = myCan.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "18px arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Canvas resolution matches page resolution",myCan.width/2,myCan.height/2);
ctx.font = "12px arial";
ctx.fillText("Canvas resolution " + myCan.width + "px by " + myCan.height + "px",myCan.width/2,myCan.height/2 + 18);
ctx.textAlign = "right";
ctx.fillText("Resize by clicking [full page]",myCan.width -10,20);
// resize function
function resizeCan(){
    myCan.width = window.innerWidth; 
    myCan.height = window.innerHeight;    
    ctx.font = "18px arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText("Resized canvas resolution matches page resolution",myCan.width/2,myCan.height/2);
    ctx.font = "12px arial";
    ctx.fillText("Canvas resolution " + myCan.width + "px by " + myCan.height + "px",myCan.width/2,myCan.height/2 + 18);
}
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCan);
```

```css
    html, body {
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    canvas {
        background:#aaa;
    }
```

```html
    <canvas id="myCan"></canvas>
```

> **Note** that you need to resize the canvas when the page resizes by listening to the window resize. The above example will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Body by default doesn't have height. You could do.

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

This will give the body a height so the canvas can grow the that size

Answer (score 0):

You could add `position:fixed;` and `left:0; top:0;` to your style. This will keep your canvas on full screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas></canvas>
<style>
canvas{
    background-color: #FF0000; 
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}    
</style>
</body>
</html>
```